# How to remove image file in Git

Tags: git

[image]

I'm trying to remove png image by `git rm file-name` command. But, I'm unable to remove this file please give a solution.

Comment: Careful: If the image is already part of history, the cleanup is a bit more complex than this.

Comment: What exactly is the problem when using `git rm` command?

Answer (score 1):

```
git rm path_to_your_file
git commit -m "Delete my file"
```

Answer (score 0):

lets see, you already removed the file, and you need to commit it.... i mean you need to add and commit it, and the file will no longer be tracked in the repository...

Your main goal to remove the file maybe to untrack the file, the "deleted" there means that it's going to be deleted in the repo, so you need to commit it, and you can get it removed.

Simply, just add, commit, and push that delete action.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if your git server is separated from your local machine you need also need to use

```
git push
```

to sync your local repository and your server

Answer (score 0):

your need to stage it

```
git add filename.png
```

and commit it

```
git commit -m 'remove image'
```

Answer (score 0):

in fact, you have already remove the file. git status only shows the latest status what you just did. you can try like this: commit and then reset to this commit id, you will find the working tree is clean.

Answer (score 0):

Since images can be png files, you can use the following command to delete them

`rm -r 'file-name.png'`